# Set proxy_http_version at the server level in NGINX config

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use NGINX as a reverse proxy server and have too many `location` blocks with a `proxy_pass` directive in my config. I want to use HTTP 1.1 globally. In all examples on the internet `proxy_http_version` is set inside each `location` block. But can I just set it once on the `server` level?

The [official documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version) says it is possible. But I can't find a single example where it is done this way. I am afraid of some problems.

Comment: You seen to have found your answer. That link is exactly where I would go looking for the answer. The next step is to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked it out myself on a running system. The documentation is correct. `proxy_http_version` inside a `server` block affects all child `location` blocks.